# Android/Gradle: conditionally apply plugin based on build type

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I would like to make something like (pseudo code):

```
if (BuildType == "release"){
    apply plugin: 'testfairy'
} else if (BuildType == "debug"){
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}
```

The idea is that based on the build type, apply (or not) a plugin. How to do it ?

Comment: I have asked the same question on Gradle forum: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-plugin-based-on-build-type-android/15265

Comment: I'm interested too. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Stefan Oehme](https://discuss.gradle.org/users/st_oehme), a Gradle core developer, he [said](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-plugin-based-on-build-type-android/15265/2?u=jffiorillo):

> Plugins can't be applied to only "part of your project". They are either applied or not. What is the use case where this becomes a problem for you?

So, the answer is **this is not possible**. I have exposed [my use cases](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-apply-plugin-based-on-build-type-android/15265/3?u=jffiorillo) where this is becomes a problem and I'll see what hi says about it.

Comment: @jason-grife has the answer, it should be marked as the solution to this question

Comment: This is a weird self-answer, because the question as worded isn't asking if plugins can only be applied to *part* of a project; it's asking if there is a way to *conditionally* apply a plugin to the *entire* project.

Comment: We are using a plugin which is actually for release builds. Debug builds does not use it. So I want to skip it for debug builds to speed up builds. In my opinion, this is a valid use case.

Answer (score 26):

With Gradle 4.6, the following works:

```
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Release")) {
    apply plugin: 'testfairy'
} else if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains("Debug")) {
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, we had need of this to only apply the performance monitoring to prod releases.  Adding it to dev/debug builds increased the cold build times by almost 1 minute or more.  We opted to not impact our devs everytime they built locally.  Our solution was slightly different but it worked.

Comment: worked on android studio with gradle 7.4

Comment: this works on Android studio and on command line if you give variant, but it will not work if your give at command line
./gradlew build

to build all variants at once.

Comment: This is the right answer! I've been looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround solution I used. The idea is to introduce an Env variable and only apply the plugin in some specific env.

```
if (System.getenv("PROJECT_ENV") == "Release") {
    apply plugin: 'your plugin'
}
```

Comment: This is close to the right solution but try using firebase perfmon and see that this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here was the solution I had that did not crash the app.  Other solutions did crash when the class was finally called with a Class not found exception.

```
def tasks = gradle.startParameter.taskNames[0] ?: ""
if (tasks.toLowerCase().contains("prod")) {
    println "Firebase-Performance pluign applied..."
    apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember maven profiles? You can do something similar using this snippet which was borrowed from gradle-fury

in your build file

 `if (project.hasProperty('profile') && project.profile.split(',').contains("ci")) {
//do something
}`

then run it when
`gradlew -Pprofile=ci`

There's a complete example here https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury/blob/develop/build.gradle

Disclaimer, i work on gradle-fury. for science