# Conditionally apply GMS google-services plugin

Tags: android, kindle-fire, google-play-services

I have been very careful not to introduce Google-Android dependencies into my Android application over the years and have two flavors keeping that segregation, `withAmazon` and `withGoogle`.

```
app
 |_ main
 |_ test
 |_ withAmazon
 |_ withGoogle
```

Recently, I've been experimenting with *Firebase Analytics* which is very much a [Google OHA only](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Handset_Alliance) product and I do not believe it is meant to work outside of the Google ecosystem (although there are [some reports](https://www.novoda.com/blog/firebase-on-amazon-devices/) it does). Part of the set-up for firebase is applying the `google-services` plugin.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

However, the `withAmazon` flavour does not include a `google-service.json` ...because...well, it's not for Google.

```
app
 |_ main
 |_ test
 |_ withAmazon
    |- java
    |- AndroidManifest.xml
 |_ withGoogle
    |- java
    |- AndroidManifest.xml
    |- google-services.json
```

...but since [Gradle plugins appear to need to have to be applied project wide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128315/1348379) is it possible to only apply the gms plugin to one of the flavours? The build fails in the scenario described above when compiling the Amazon flavor since it complains about the `google-services.json` not existing...which is correct.

Right now, my workaround is to move the `google-services.json` under  the `app/` directory. Problem solved. However, it doesn't feel right that my very clear divide between Google & the 'pure' Android OS is being encroached upon.

Any assistance graciously received.

Comment: Then make firebase only a part of `withGoogle` flavour, or move `google-services.json` to the main flavor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by modifying my parent build.gradle file like so;

```
if (getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString().contains(withGoogleFlavor)){
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Now the plugin (and associated Google Play Services dependencies) are not added to the Amazon flavour of my app. Moreover, the `google-services.json` now lives back under the "withGoogle" flavor.

Note: `withGoogle` is a def defined elsewhere with value "withGoogle".
Acknowledgement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336869/1348379